# General function for all value types in class

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm trying to accomplish the following within a class:

```
public void Test(var input)
{
    WriteToFile(input.ToString());
}

private void WriteToFile(string input)
{
    .....
}
```

But the 'var' statement can not be used within a class. So I'm wondering what the easiest way is to accomplish the same thing as above.

One solution would be to create a function for each value type, but that must be more trouble than necessary:

```
public void Test(string input)
{
    WriteToFile(input);
}

public void Test(int input)
{
    WriteToFile(input.ToString());
}

public void Test(double input)
{
    WriteToFile(input.ToString());
}

private void WriteToFile(string input)
{
    .....
}
```

**EDIT**: When giving it some more thought I understood that this wasn't really the answer to my problems. I'm posting a new question that has more thought behind it. I'm not gonna delete this question though since someone else might find this usefull.

Comment: Just use the base class of them all, `object` instead of `var`.

Comment: Use `object`? `public void Test(object input)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just pass `object` and call `ToString()` on it:

```
public void Test(object input)
{
    WriteToFile(input.ToString());
}
```

Comment: What if input is not string?

Comment: I think , either Convert.ToString() could be a better option

Comment: Every object has method `ToString()` and the default implementation of it returns type name. Read more here [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring.aspx). As long as object is not null it is safe to use.

Answer (score 6):

```
public void Test<T>(T input)
{
    WriteToFile(Convert.ToString(input));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try to use
    `public void Test(object input)`

and maybe test (input!= null) before calling the tostring method

Answer (score 0):

Make the function Test accepting an object parameter and proceed after determining the type inside it.

```
public void Test(object input)
{
      var res = (dynamic)null;
      if (input.GetType() == typeof(String)))
      {
            res = input.ToString();
            WriteToFile(res);
      }
}
```

EDIT: Why this method ?

In future, if you need to extend support to other types as well, you could do something like below (as the question talks about float, double, long, int...)

```
public void Test(object input)
{
      var res = (dynamic)null;
      if (input.GetType() == typeof(String)))
      {
            res = input.ToString();
            WriteToFile(res);
      }
      if (input.GetType() == typeof(float)))
      {
           //do some other operations here...
      }
}
```

Even nicer way of implementing this would be using "is" operator.

```
      if (input is string)
      {
            res = input.ToString();
            WriteToFile(res);
      }
```

Comment: I don't see why this type checking or the use of `dynamic` would be necessary.

Comment: Also, `object.GetType() == typeof(String)` doesn't even compile.

Comment: @Henrik: I am slightly uncomfortable with the accepted answer because what if the "input" is not a string? An exception can be thrown in this case..

Comment: @Henrik: as for your question, why a dynamic null? Just because, i don't like to play with the "input" (passed in) parameter and a safer way after you determine the type of input parameter

Comment: What if the input is not a string? It will not throw an exception.

Comment: @Henrik: Whats wrong in my methodology? Isn't type checking in a if statement makes the work more clearer and safer ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32869/discussion-between-henrik-and-now-he-who-must-not-be-named)